# Remove Duplicates from select query

Tags: postgresql

```sql
SELECT distinct(product_id), id 
FROM stock_move 
WHERE date >= '2019-09-24 00:00:00' 
and date <= '2019-09-24 23:59:59'
```

with this query, I still, get results like

```
    |250, 1256
    |250, 1257
    |259, 1258
```

but I don't want to select duplicates. so from first to rows, I need just one to be selected. How can I aceave this?

Desired output.

```
    |250, 1256
    |259, 1258
```

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. It always applies to **all** columns in the SELECT list. Putting parentheses around one column won't change that. `distinct (a),b` is exactly the same as `distinct a, (b)` or `distinct a,b` - you are probably looking for `distinct on ()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses in your query are insignificant, the query is identical to

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id, id
FROM stock_move
WHERE date >= '2019-09-24 00:00:00' and date <= '2019-09-24 23:59:59';
```

So duplicates will only be removed if both `product_id` and `id` are the same.

To get what you want, use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id) product_id, id
FROM stock_move
WHERE date >= '2019-09-24 00:00:00' and date <= '2019-09-24 23:59:59';
```

This will output only one row for each `product_id`.

If you want to have some control over *which* row is returned, add an `ORDER BY` clause.